# Spring Boot CSRF protection on Spring CloudGateway for Microservice Architecture

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cookies, csrf

I have created two different projects.

1. API Gateway - Using Spring Cloud Gateway Netflix Eureka Server
2. Identity Service - Using Spring Security in this project.

I have read multiple suggestions online to keep Authentication and Authorization separate from API Gateway and hence Identity Service is being used.

I am using SPA (Reactjs) and want to use Double Submit Cookie to protect the secured endpoints.

Logic currently implement:

1. Csrf request goes to Identity Service and returns the csrf cookie using UUID random.
2. Now, Login requests go to Identity Service and it returns the session cookie with HttpOnly and generates a new csrf token with every subsequent request.
3. Csrf token is sent using axios using withCredentials: true and it works fine.
4. API Gateway has a filter to validate the session jwt and the csrf. For csrf, currently, the logic is comparing X-Xsrf-Token from the header and the XSRF-TOKEN from the cookie and if both are equal then it's valid.

Now, the problem.

I can copy both session and csrf from the cookie section from Devtools and submit the same token via Postman to the same endpoint and it basically authenticates and shares the response.

Now, as per my understanding, this should have given csrf token error if done in the correct way. I have tried the same method with Laravel Sanctum and it returns Csrf 419 error as expected.

Any idea, what to add to get the correct behavior?